# Finding the character occupying a particular index in a string

Tags: python

I have a the string 'Hello', I need to find out what characters occupy which indexes.

Pseudo-code:

```
string = 'Hello'
a = string.index(0)
b = string.index(4)
print a , b
```

a would be 'H' and b would be 'o'.

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  What chapter are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = "Hello"
print a[0]
print a[4]
```

Answer (score 4):

String (`str`) in Python is a [sequence type](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange), and thus can be accessed with `[]`:

```
my_string = 'Hello'

a = my_string[0]
b = my_string[4]

print a, b # Prints H o
```

This means it also supports slicing, which is the standard way to get a substring in Python:

```
print my_string[1:3] # Prints el
```

Comment: In anticipation of the lack of Python experience in the guy asking this question, I might add that it might not be a good idea to name a variable after an existing module, `string` in this case.

Comment: @Jim a deprecated module nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

I think he is asking for this

```
 for index,letter in enumerate('Hello'):
    print 'Index Position ',index, 'The Letter ', letter
```

And maybe we want to explore some data structures

so lets add a dictionary - I can do this lazily since I know that index values are unique

```
index_of_letters={}
for index,letter in enumerate('Hello'):
    index_of_letters[index]=letter
index_of_letters
```